# multiprocessing of python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am a bird for python,I want to translate some file, so I write a python shell.When I did it, that something wrong. It not work, I print result.I think it is wrong the code works but translate fail.I don't know what it is not works.

```
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x102ee3990>
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x102ee3a10>
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x102ee3ad0>



#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding=utf-8

from multiprocessing import Pool
from googletrans import Translator
import os
import sys
import re    
import urllib,urllib2
from time import time
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding( "utf-8" ) 


def Gtranslate(pregs):
    filepath='./test/'
    pathDir =  os.listdir(filepath)
    for allDir in pathDir:
        filename = os.path.join('%s%s' % (filepath, allDir))
        content = open(filename,'r').read()
        for preg in pregs: 
            rex=re.search(preg,content)
            if rex:
                translator = Translator()
                res=translator.translate(rex.group(1), dest='zh-CN').text
                content = re.sub(preg,rex.group().replace(rex.group(1),res),content)
                print res

        with open(filename,'w+') as f:
            f.write(content)


def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    partterns = ("script_name\s*\(\s*english\s*:\s*\"([\s\S]*?)\"\s*\)\s*;","script_set_attribute\s*\(\s*attribute\s*:\s*\"\s*solution\s*\"\s*,\s*value\s*:\s*\"([\s\S]*?)\"\s*\)\s*;","script_set_attribute\s*\(\s*attribute\s*:\s*\"\s*description\s*\"\s*,\s*value\s*:\s*\"([\s\S]*?)\"\s*\)\s*;")  

    for par in partterns:
        result = pool.apply_async(Gtranslate, (par, ))
        print result
        print par
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    if result.successful():
        print 'successful'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1=time()
    main()
    print "cost time is: {:.2f}s".format(time() - t1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get result from [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult), call [`AsyncResult.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get):

```
for par in partterns:
    result = pool.apply_async(Gtranslate, (par, ))
    print par, result.get()
```

But, this will prevent parallel executions.

Instead collect async results, then call `AsyncResult.get` after all patterns submitted to subprocess.

```
async_results = []
for par in patterns:
    result = pool.apply_async(Gtranslate, (par,))
    async_results.append((par, result))
for par, result in async_results:
    print par
    print result.get()
```